# axios.get return 500 internal server error

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I want to fetch record from database, I set route in `axios.get(getsitepages)` where in route.js file admin is prefix. 
I set the same route in web.php laravel file where admin is prefix before route. When I hit on link to get data, it throws an error `Error: Request failed with status code 500`

Below is my code and what I've tried so far:

SitePages.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
  <h1> test </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            pages:[],
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.FetchSitePages();
    },
    methods:{
        FetchSitePages(){
            axios.get('getsitepages')
            .then(({data}) =>{
                console.log("data");
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

web.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
Route::get('getsitepages',[PagesController::class, 'getsitepages'])->name('getsitepages');
});
```

routes.js

```
import DashboardLayout from "../layout/admin/MainLayout.vue";

const routes = [{
    path: "/admin",
    component: DashboardLayout,
    name: "dashboard",
    meta: { title: "Devoint dashboard" },
    children: [{
        path: '',
        component: () =>
            import ('../Pages/Home.vue'),
        name: 'home'
    },
    {
        path: 'pages',
        component: () =>
            import ('../Pages/SitePages.vue'),
        name: 'pages'
    }]
}]


export default routes;
```

PagesController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getsitepages(){
       die('test');
    }
}
```

Above is my code, please help me to find where i am mistaken?

Comment: 500 error means something went wrong on the server side (laravel side).
Have you tried not calling die('test') in your controller and instead returning an actual response. Like "return response()->json(["success" => true]);"

Comment: even better, have you checked the logs ? laravel's log and the server log.

Comment: @N69S no i did not check.

Comment: @Ian it still showing me same error, after return response.